# Can't figure out small errors in my code?

Tags: python

MY CODES PROBLEMS 3 and 4:

```
def avg_weight(diet, data):
acc = []
grams = data.items()
for (name , food , weights) in grams:
   if diet == food:
       acc.append([weights])
       total = sum(acc)
       avg = total / len(acc)
 return avg
```

up above I get a syntax error with the `acc.append([weights])` line for some reason

#### 3:

```
def word_positions(phrase):
    str.split(phrase)
    for num in phrase:
        return (num + ":" + str(phrase[num])
```

I get a random EOF error for some reason.

Thanks guys!

Comment: can you fix Indentation first?

Comment: Remove the square brackets around `weights`

Answer (score 0):

If the output you are expecting is:

```
0:t
1:e
2:s
3:t
```

Then:

```
def word_positions (phrase):
    str.split(phrase)
    for num in range(0,len(phrase)) :
        return str(num) + ":"+str(phrase[num])
```

For the other problem provide the input that you are expecting